# django sync db to get two apps in two databases

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps, django-orm

I'm not sure how it works but I need two different models/apps in separated databases. So if I try `syncdb --database db1` will get all installed apps into db1. So question is how to get just one app in another db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing) which will filter models based on application and database in its `allow_syncdb` method. You cas start from the `AuthRouter` example in the documentation.